# Discord Bot Question: Sending Image with Discord.io / Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.io

I'm trying to send an image with my discord bot. I've found a few references online that are Discord.js specific, but it seems that the first step for those answers is to have a constant variable Discord requiring Discord.js. When I apply that line, I'm always told by my bot that variable Discord is already established, so I'm trying to go about the task differently.

I don't have an error line to report, the bot doesn't crash which would give me a report in power shell. When I type img, it just doesn't send anything. Which is progress, but I would really appreciate another set of eyes. I'm in no way a pro here, and I'll be the first to admit it.

Thank you!

```js
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
  colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
  token: auth.token,
  autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
  logger.info('Connected');
  logger.info('Logged in as: ');
  logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
  // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
  // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
  if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];
    args = args.splice(1);
    switch (cmd) {
      //IMAGE
      case 'img':
        bot.uploadFile({
          to: channelID,
          File: 'https://i.ibb.co/09sy2ZT/Enemy1.png'
        });
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you come across this issue, don't use a weblink! Use pathing instead!

If your image is in the folder where you coding is, you can just use the image file name. Otherwise you can use './ImageFolderName/Imgname.png'

You can also apparently use './ImageFolderName/'+arrayname[index].arrayattribute+'.png'

If you want that image to be array quality specific.